# How can I set-up Sonar to identify slow tests and fail the build?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I'm using Maven to build a Java project. I'd like to fail the build if there are slow tests. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Sonar does not execute any tests itself. Therefore setting up Sonar to do what you want to achieve is probably not the thing you want to do.

Instead the maven surefire plugin executes your tests. The surefire results are then pushed to sonar.

Assuming you are using junit: as documented [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Timeout-for-tests) simply say:

```
@Test(timeout=1000)
```

If you want a specific test to fail if it runs for more than 1000 milliseconds.

If you want to define a timeout for all tests in a class, you must define a test Rule:

```
 @Rule
 public Timeout globalTimeout = Timeout.seconds(10); // 10 seconds max per method tested
```

Comment: Your solution is good, but having SonarQube break the build for slow tests is certainly a valid quality check. With JUnit failing the tests, the pipeline is stopped. Static analysis and other checks aren't executed, which may not be what OP wanted..

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this by implementing such a mechanic yourself:

```
public static void executeTimeLimited(Runnable r, long nanosMax, boolean printElapsedTime) throws Exception
{
    long nanosStart = System.nanoTime();
    r.run();
    long nanosElapsed = System.nanoTime() - nanosStart;
    if (printElapsedTime)
        System.out.println("Runnable " + r.toString() + " took " + Long.toString(nanosElapsed) + " nanos."); // Adjust with logging framework of choice
    if (nanosElapsed > nanosMax)
        throw new Exception("Execution of " + r.toString() + " took " + Long.toString(nanosElapsed) + " nanoseconds, was only allowed to run " + Long.toString(nanosMax) + " nanos (diff " + Long.toString(nanosMax - nanosElapsed) + ")");
}
```

Now, in the future, wrap your tested code like this

```
TestingUtil.executeTimeLimited(() -> {
    foo1();
    somethingElse();
    moreCodeHere();
    // your code here
}, 10000000000 /* 10 seconds */, true);
```

The above is utilizing lambda expressions from Java 8. You may have to use a anonymous inner class if you are still on Java 7, though I recommend upgrading, since lambda expressions are faster to execute, which might be important for small timespans.